# Is it possible that a NancyHost uses another host name than localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, server, localhost, nancy

Creating a Nancy self-hosted console application requires the local address including the PORT as parameter:

```
using (var host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:1234")))
{
   host.Start();
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

While customizing the PORT is a valid use case, is it possible to use another HOST than ("http://localhost"). If yes, which ones and for which reason?

**Backgroud:**

I am creating a custom settings file for the server and I wonder if it is enough to provide a setting 'Port' or is it better to provide a setting 'Host' (or 'URL') that includes the HOST as well as the PORT?

**Edit**

To avoid hardcoding, the HOST part may be configurable via application settings (App.config) which is different to the custom settings file that is used by the server's administrator. However, I want to keep the custom settings file as simple as possible. Therefere, the question: Is there is any thinkable reason that the part 'http://localhost' should be modified?

Comment: Are you asking if it OK to hard code localhost in your code? If so the answer is a resounding no, even if you believe it will never change. It's just common practice.

Comment: @tomredfern: pleas see the updated question.

Comment: Are you asking that regardless of which environment you deploy the service to, will it always use localhost?

Comment: The server will be deployed (as windows service) to a Windows Server 2016. `will it always use localhost`? That is the question. Is it possible that a server uses another host than localhost?

Comment: So your question should actually be "Is it possible that a Nancy service uses another host name than localhost?", and not "Should I make host name configurable" ;-)

Comment: Yes... that is actually the subjacent question ;) I'll change the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

The NancyHost constructor needs a valid Uri object, and to create that you can't get around specifying a HOST. Depending on your application make the HOST editable either inside your program, some form of communication or via a settings file. Do not hardcode the HOST as localhost, even if you think it's gonna stay that way, it's good practice to keep things modifiable. If you want your settings file to be as simple as possible, split it into 2 files:

basicSettings

advancedSettings

where advancedSettings only contains things you rarely, if ever, change und basicSettings contain the things you expect to be changed more frequently.

There might be a case at some point in time where you want to connect to another host because NancyHost has moved, either to the cloud or another system in the same network(the latter is more probable). Just in case this happens you should make it modifiable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll go that way with the 2 settings files (where the advanced one is the default application settings file: App.config).

Comment: However, I didn't get the point of the last part _There might be a case at some point in time where you want to connect to another host..._. `NancyHost` is the server and it is always listen on localhost (the computer it is running on). So where is the use case to change that part? That is actually the point I am interested in ;)